# CSS class gets applied in IE 8 and IE 9 but not in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

I have a peculiar problem. I am trying to "modernize" and old application made for old IEs, to work in IE 11. But somehow a CSS class is not getting applied on DOM element.

CSS is very simple:

```
.header {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    background: url(/pricemanager/static/img/bg_header.png) repeat-x left top;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #717273;
}
```

This is how the developer tools look like in IE 8, IE 9 and IE 11 respectively:

[image: IE 8]

[image: IE 9]

[image: IE 11]

The weird thing is that after page reload in IE 11, it looks for a second the class was applied, but its gone in next moment. I've checked, and there is no javascript manipulating this DOM object AFAIK. I've checked the network trace and css file gets loaded in all three browsers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the stylesheet being included inside an IE conditional comment?

Comment: No. style sheet is called pm2.base.css and it can be seen in IE 11 screen shot, but class is somehow not applied.

Comment: Perhaps the syntax is malformed before the `.header` class. Is `.header` the only class that doesn't seem to be applied? Maybe worth creating a fiddle if you can or show us the CSS preceding the `.header` class.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I'll try to reproduce it in fiddle. I have a feeling extjs (3.4) might have something to do with this, but Google did not turn up anything so far. On first glance, this is the only class that doesn't get applied. Syntax seems pretty ok to me:

<div class="header">

Comment: Thanks. Going on the CSS and info you have provided everything looks OK and should work. If the CSS file isn't being included via a conditional comment my only thought at the moment is that there may be a syntax error in the CSS file causing the rule to be ignored. Does the class get applied in other non-IE browsers?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I've only tried it in chrome (latest) and it gets applied. Everything looks OK to me as well, that is why this is so puzzling =) As I mentioned, it's an old application (10+ years) with little or no structure in the code or regard for best practices. I am using modern ie virtual machine to test things from https://modern.ie/en-us .

IE 11 seems to have problems even in compatibility modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the reason for why this is happening, but I moved css for navigation in a separate file and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is some CSS overwrite such as CSS-hacks specifically for IE7?

```
.header{
*margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: I found a hack or two, removed them, but no difference so far. I'll dig deeper.